# Mobile version of web zoomed in by default

Tags: mobile, viewport, meta, responsive

If you visit my web through a mobile device (or at least iphone, I could not check any other device) www.oxynergy.com you will notice that everytime you open any page, it is JUST a little bit zoomed in, you can pinch screen and zoom it out, but it shouldnt be like that. I checked the viewport meta and as far as my understanding goes, it works fine, can anyone help me with this?

This is the viewport meta right now:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your layout width is set to device-width, but there's elements on your page that are wider than that so the browser allows you to zoom out.

In your case, there's `<div class="row visible-xs">` in your `<footer>`. It's the negative margins that are causing the box to expand to wider than the 100% of the containing block. Similarly, the `class=vc_row` s in your `class=container`  has the same issue. Removing the `margin-left|right` styles on `.vc_row` and `.row` fixes the issue.

I don't know layout well enough to know what you're trying to accomplish or what the right method is but you need to do that without causing these boxes to become wider than 100% of the container. Otherwise you'll have content that's wider than the screen width and that'll allow zooming out. If you just set a minimum-scale, it'll still be possible to scroll to it (though I suppose you could set overflow-x: hidden, but that's just masking over the problem).

Comment: You are the best man! That was the problem. Now im facing some css "issue" that i will try to fix it my self, but this solved my problem